# What's the best way to run shell command from GUI app written in Rust?

Tags: macos, shell, rust, environment-variables, gtk

My app is a GTK4 GUI app. At some point, it needs to execute NodeJS as a child process / external command.

I know I can do this using `std::process::Command` API. However, this works only when I start the app from shell. If I launch it using the OS GUI (i.e: clicking its launch icon), the command fails because:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

And the command I'm trying to run starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

So it is unable to find Node executable due to missing ENV vars.

I know the child process inherits the env from the parent by default and I can set ENV vars explicitly using `std::process::Command::env` and `std::process::Command::envs`. But is this what I'm supposed to do? I mean, set the env vars manually? Isn't there a better way?

Basically, I want to use the same env settings regardless of how the app is launched. It should work the same way when I start it from dock, a terminal window or using the launchpad etc.

This is MacOSX 14.2.1

The rust code that starts runs Node is just a simple function (for now):

```
async fn run_node(
    executor: String,
    command: String,
    cwd: String,
    params: Vec<Param>,
) -> Child {
    let mut cmd = Command::new(executor);

    cmd.current_dir(cwd);
    cmd.arg(command);

    for param in params {
        cmd.arg(format!("--{}", param.name));
        if param.value.len() > 0 {
            cmd.arg(format!("{}", param.value));
        }
    }

    let child = cmd
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    child
}
```

The child process is executed in a separate thread:

```
// This lives in an event handler. This is how child process gets created

 sender.oneshot_command(async move {
   CommandMsg::Data(run_node(executor, command, cwd, params).await)
 });

// And this is where the child actually gets executed. It is triggered by the event emitted above:

fn update_cmd(
        &mut self,
        message: Self::CommandOutput,
        sender: ComponentSender<Self>,
        _: &Self::Root,
    ) {
        match message {
            CommandMsg::Data(mut child) => {
                self.set_output::<ChildStdout>(sender.clone(), child.stdout.take(), false);
                self.set_output::<ChildStderr>(sender.clone(), child.stderr.take(), true);

                std::thread::spawn(move || {
                    child.wait().unwrap();
                    sender.input(ExecutorInput::Done);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

This is all implemented using the Relm4 Command API:

https://relm4.org/book/stable/threads_and_async/commands.html

The `executor` is an absolute path to the NodeJS executable (not Node itself, but a CLI written in Node) and the `command` is just a command argument for the CLI. So it looks like this:

```
/path/to/executor command --arg1 --arg2
```

The app is packaged as an OSX App Bundle, it can be installed from DMG image. So it lives in /Applications and it can de started the same way as any other OSX GUI app.

Comment: When you start a program from the shell (bash or whatever), it inherits the environment of the shell, but when you start it from the desktop GUI there is no shell there. Any env. variable that is set from `.bashrc`, for example, will not be set from the GUI. I don't know how MacOSX sets up the desktop environment, but surely there is a file to setup the environment properly, maybe in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/`?

Comment: It might be an OS X issue, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x).  Specifically, you may have set `PATH` via `.bashrc` (or whatever equivalent for the shell being used) and then you never used `launchctl setenv` to do the similar.  Please verify that's been done first before launching the application from GUI.

Comment: @rodrigo so am I supposed to parse those profile files and set the env manually? I was hoping there is a way to do that automatically, but I guess not?

Comment: Rather than parse `.bashrc`, can you just manually set the `PATH` to what it should be?

Comment: You shouldn't need parsing a shell script. If you control the script you are running you could just add `source /etc/profile` at the beginning. If you cannot change that you could write a wrapper script for that program or a wrapper for your GTK4 app that sets the environment.

Comment: Env vars are private to each process. They are normally inherited from the parent process; although, the parent process can specify a custom set of env vars when starting a new process. If you are setting env vars in a shell config script such as *~/.bashrc* then those env vars won't be available to a process started by something other than an interactive shell. Env vars are not global. Your mental model for how env vars work is incorrect.

Comment: Show the Rust code which starts the script. Also descripe how you start the Rust GUI app.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses! I think running source /path/profile is not ideal, because these config files differ from shell to shell. and the shell env is not shared with the GUI anyway. Tried using `launchctl setenv`, but it doesn't seem to work, even if I set the exact same PATH I have in bash.  Probably using a plist file could help as described in the linked thread, will try. @user1934428 I added the relevant code snippet

Comment: You did not show how you call `run_node`. We need to know what is stored in `executor` and in `command`. You also did not describe how (and from where)  you start your Rust program; this is important to get an idea, what the environment of your Rust application contains. For debugging, I would also print the value of `env::var("PATH")` before invoking `run_node`.

Comment: @user1934428 Added some more code. Also added info about the args. As for how and where Rust program is started, I'm not sure what you mean. It's started like any other GUI app, from launchpad. Is this not what you mean?

Comment: Ah, from _launchpad_. And did you set the variable `PATH` in your program? Alternatively you can specify the absolute path of _command_ in the same way is you did it for _executor_. Otherwise, how should the poor executor know, where to find the command?

Comment: Yes it was the PATH env variable, which was empty. However, I was able to set it only via `std::process::Command::env`. Placing a plist file in locations described by the `launchctl` man page didn't help. `launchctl setenv` also didn't work. Anyway it works no, thanks guys!